# Async RabbitMQ consume message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq

I'm trying to get a message from RabbitMQ and doing it async and wait for the message.
When calling the method below from a Console app it works. But when trying to call this method from a MVC controller I get stuck at tsc.Task.
Using the RabbitMQ UI I know there is a message in the queue to consume.

```
 public async Task<string> WaitForMessage(string queueName)
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
        durable: true,
        exclusive: false,
        autoDelete: false,
        arguments: null);

        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        var tag = channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        consumer.Received += async (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Body.ToArray());
            await Task.Yield();
            channel.BasicAck(eventArgs.DeliveryTag, false);
            tcs.SetResult(message);
        };

        string result = await tcs.Task; //.ConfigureAwait(false);
        return result;
    }
```

I'm initialize rabbit MQ the same way in both apps.
When inspecting the UI of RabbitMQ I can see that the connection is created from the MVC app. And when setting BasicConsume I see that the queue no longer has any message ready and that the message is Unacknowledged. When killing the app the message in the queue get status ready again and is no longer Unacknowledged.

I'm using v6.4.0 of RabbitMQ Client

Comment: A console app does not have a synchronization context, the non-core ASP.NET does. So you must be deadlocking at the `await Task.Yield()` because you are already in `await tcs.Task`, which would not happen in console due to the lack of a synchronization context.

Comment: @GSerg - I never hit the breakpoint in the method assigned consumer.Received.

Comment: Since your handler never seems to be firing, you may have forgotten to set`DispatchConsumersAsync` when you create the connection factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had conflicting versions of System.Memory so upon returning to my received-method the error was triggered.

I found this out by adding channel.CallbackException that caught an exception.